# How can I slide the layout with action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, slidingdrawer

How can I slide the layout with action bar ?
Right now my navigation drawer list just appear below the action bar, but I want it to overlap the action bar `onclick` of navigation drawer icon; can I do this?

Comment: link of image as i want to overlap the list of navigation bar on action bar http://i.stack.imgur.com/AOntE.png

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use sliding pane layout 
Here is a link 
https://github.com/cricklet/Android-PanesLibrary/tree/master/example

you can slide the layout with action bar
you have to make a sliding pane and then navigation drawer in the 2nd view 
which you will get after implement this example
and here is the link for navigation drawer 
http://www.codeofaninja.com/2014/02/android-navigation-drawer-example.html
combine these examples
it can help you a lot!!

Comment: It not helping me properly can you please other way to fix this ?

Comment: For this you have to use sliding pane for one fragment and navigation drawer for the other fragment 
http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/10/android-slidingpanelayout-tutorial.html
first of all try this link for the first part 
you can add options in the list according to your requirement if you use this example

Comment: Now i under stand your problem you only have to use sliding pane layout to slide the view 
when the user click on the action bar icon the view slides from left to right

Answer (score 0):

Navigation drawer usually stays below action bar so you can slide it out or open it via the navigation button. Based on the image you posted, I think you should use this well-known lib: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu.

It takes some steps to set up but when you're done you can customize it the way you want easily. The author also provided demo on Google Play Store and Youtube for you to review.